# ActionBar in PreferenceFragment not recalculating height and font size

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-orientation, preferenceactivity, android-appcompat

Using the latest `AppCompat-v21` library, I used `ActionBarActivity` to create and populate the `PreferenceFragment`. However, the `ActionBar` does not seem to change height and the text size when the orientation or screen size is altered. Testing this on other activities as well, this behavior only seems to be happening in `PreferenceActivity` (opposed to this question asked here: [ActionBar capacity/overflow not changing on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625964/actionbar-capacity-overflow-not-changing-on-orientation-change) ).

First of all, to handle orientation changes, I added `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to the Manifest. I suspect that this is the main reason for this problem, but as I mentioned earlier, this works on other `Activity`s.

Here are some screenshots that explain the issue:

Launched `PreferenceActivity` in Portrait mode:

[image: Portrait start]

Rotated to Landscape from Portrait:

[image: rotate to landscape]

Launched `PreferenceActivity` in Landscape mode:

[image: landscape]

Rotated to Portrait from Landscape:

[image: rotate to portrait]

**Additional Information**

Here is the `PreferenceActivity` class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class PrefsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

Is this behavior a bug? If not, is there a workaround or a fix?

---

**EDIT I**

I tried using the new `ToolBar` widget, but no luck.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class PrefsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pref);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pref_frame, new PrefsFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Same problem here. But in my case the font size is simply too small in landscape, no matter how it is started...

Comment: Have you tried to define `textSize` in styles.xml ? Sometimes, android will got a bug when you are not define a determined value. You can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16189877/3922207 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12899367/3922207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:configChanges` is not recommended because orientation, keyboard are not the only causes of Activity recreation.

So, the better approach is to remove this from the Manifest, and set `setRetainInstance(true);` on the `Fragment` class. This will bypass this destroy-and-recreate cycle of the Fragment, while refreshing the Activity.

Since the `Toolbar` is included in the Activity and not the Fragment, this will refresh the Toolbar while keeping the Fragment.

In case of Dialogs, the usage of the [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to close/reopen them will work.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 3):

I can offer this solution.

Works with system ActionBar, with Lollipop Toolbar and AppCompat Toolbar.

```
public static void fixActionBar(Activity activity, View toolbar)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        if (toolbar == null)
        {
            int id = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
            if (id != 0) toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(id);
        }
        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            Context context = toolbar.getContext();
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]
                    {android.R.attr.actionBarStyle, android.R.attr.actionBarSize});
            int actionStyle = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
            int actionHeight = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 0);
            typedArray.recycle();
            try
            {
                View container = (View) toolbar.getParent();
                Field field = container.getClass().getDeclaredField("mHeight");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.setInt(container, actionHeight);
                View overlay = (View) container.getParent();
                field = overlay.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionBarHeight");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.setInt(overlay, actionHeight);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            toolbar.getLayoutParams().height = actionHeight;
            toolbar.setMinimumHeight(actionHeight);
            typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(actionStyle, new int []
                    {android.R.attr.titleTextStyle});
            ((Toolbar) toolbar).setTitleTextAppearance(context, typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0));
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method from onConfigurationChanged of your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do the other activities you tested with also have `android:configChanges` declared on the manifest?

As you said, the problem is that

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

doesn't handle the rotation. It actually stops the activity and views from being recreated, causing the views not to read the correspondent values after a config change.

Considering the fact that you are using fragments, I would remove the `android:configChanges` attribute and have the `PrefsFragment` retain it's instance.